# ruby upgrading because of macport update failure

Tags: macos, installation, macports

I am trying to run `sudo port selfupdate`, I get permanently this message

```
Installing new MacPorts release in /opt/local as root:admin; permissions 0755; Tcl-Package in /Library/Tcl

Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error installing new MacPorts base: command execution failed
```

for info : Xcode's command line tool and Xcode's versions are uptodate. Why is it so ?

Edit :

I ran `sudo port -d selfupdate`, and I get a compile error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_reg_all_open_entries", referenced from:
      _registry_tcl_detach in registry.o
  "_reg_all_open_files", referenced from:
...

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
make[2]: *** [registry.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
Command failed: cd /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base && CC=/usr/bin/cc ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --with-tclpackage=/Library/Tcl --with-install-user=root --with-install-group=admin --with-directory-mode=0755 --enable-readline && make && make install SELFUPDATING=1
Exit code: 2
DEBUG: Error installing new MacPorts base: command execution failed
    while executing
"macports::selfupdate [array get global_options] base_updated"
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error installing new MacPorts base: command execution failed
```

Comment: at some point I figured out that macports is just too fragile, and went with brew...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in a situation to delete properly macports and the proceed to reinstallation, and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should update Xcode tools, read more here:
http://www.itechlounge.net/2013/10/mac-macports-selfupdate-failed-on-osx-mavericks/